# Functional testing :update action of JSON API in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, functional-testing, json-api

I've been struggling with this for a long time, trying who knows how many combinations - to no avail. Seems several others on SO and Google haven't been able to resolve this.

Essentially, I'm posting to the :update action on my controller within Rails 4's built-in functional testing framework. My app is strictly a JSON API, so I need to post the :update request as a JSON request. Everything works beautifully in the wild, but the functional test syntax can't seem to get a grasp of what I need.

Here's my current attempt:

```
test "should be able to update location" do

  post :update, id: 1, format: :json, '{"is_private": "false"}'

  get :show, id: 1, format: :json
  assert_equal json['data'][0]['is_private'], false

end
```

Running rake test results in a syntax error:

```
unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

For clarity's sake, my controller action looks like this:

```
def update
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  if @location.update_attributes(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read))
    api_response(@location)
  else
    respond_with api_error
  end
end
```

What am I missing here? Is it even possible to test JSON posts with Rails 4's built-in functional testing framework? The official documentation is quite terse on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubber duck programming really does work. I've got it sorted out:

```
test "should be able to update location" do

  update = { is_private: false }.to_json
  patch(:update, update, id: 1)

  get :show, id: 1, format: :json
  assert_equal json['data'][0]['is_private'], false

end
```